# Plotting 3D Regions

Tags: mathematics

How can I plot a simple 3D region such as

$$x^2+y^2+z^2<16$$

in Blender?

If I can't do that directly, how can I turn it into

$$x=\dots$$
$$y=\dots$$
$$z=\dots$$

So I can use Mesh --> Math Function --> XYZ Surface?

Or is there a script that can plot

$$x^2+y^2+z^2<16$$

by brute-forcing for each $x$, $y$, and $z$ values of step size $d$ then plotting that?

Answer (score 3):

This method is using the ***Math Function Mesh*** that you mentioned in the question.  Maybe someone else will come along with a script. For obvious reasons, you can't use X, Y, or Z values in the equations since that would setup circular dependencies.  You must use U and V:

X equation:  `4 * cos(u) * sin(v)`

Y equation:  `4 * sin(u) * sin(v)`

Z equation: `4 * cos(v)`

Where:  `0 < u < 3.14159`

and: `-3.14159 < v < 3.14159`

[image]

---

Note that you will need to remove doubles and flip the normals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) after creation.  Also note that you can enter precise values for **U** and **V** ***and they will be applied but they will only be displayed in the text box with two decimal points***.  Make sure that **U wrap** is disabled or else you will get overlapping faces.  This is after removing doubles and fixing normals:

[image]

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969798/plotting-a-point-on-the-edge-of-a-sphere