# Plotting functions in blender

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mathematics

I've played around with "fractals" following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR7jxw94Tcg

but I want to plot my own functions; is it possible to plot any (math) function in blender,

logs, polys, etc.?

Comment: Do any of these help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/using-blender-for-plotting-graphs/47526#47526 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/is-there-a-tool-for-scientific-visualization-using-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90331/plotting-3d-regions

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.